# Diverging Integrals and pointwise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a $f$ and $f_n$ such that

$(f_n) \rightarrow$ $f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$

$f$ and every $f_n$ integrable

but the sequence of integrals $\int_0^1 f_n$ does not converge

I know this is possible because the only way for the integrals to converge with $(f_n) \rightarrow$ $f$ is if $(f_n) \rightarrow$ $f$ pointwise. I can have the $n$'s taper off but their integral blowing up?

Answer (score 1):

Set $f_n=n^2\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}$. Then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, but
$$ \int_0^1f_n(x)\;dx=n^2\cdot\frac{1}{n}=n\to\infty $$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: What is the $\chi$ portion mean?

Comment: If $E$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, $\chi_E(x)$ is the function defined by $\chi_E(x)=1$ if $x\in E$, and $\chi_E(x)=0$ if $x\not\in E$. $\chi_E$ is called the characteristic function of the set $E$.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ if $x \in [0, n]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to 0, but $\int f_n = 1$, for every $n$ and $\int f = 0$

Comment: ooops... I didn't see that you need $f_n$ to be defined in $[0,1]$

Comment: Do you think you could try to find another function? :P